# Keyboard shortcut to change tab groups on Safari

Tags: macos, safari, keyboard-shortcuts

Are there any keyboard shortcut to change tab groups on Safari 15?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> to show previous / next tab group.

<sub>You can type "tab group" in the search field on Safari's Help menu. This give you a list of menu items that contains "tab group" in its name. Hover your mouse over the search result and it will show you where the menu item is, as well as its keyboard shortcut if available.</sub>

<sub>Also, Stack Overflow is for mostly programming related questions. For questions on using the Apple hardwares and softwares, use [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).</sub>

Comment: in usage depending on what page you're on, need to press up/down twice

Comment: The shortcut does not work in Safari 16.4

Comment: cmd+opt+up/down did the trick though

Comment: @Mikhail I notice that too and I'm pretty sure they broke something in 16.4.*. The menu items in *Window -> Go to Previous/Next Tab Group* still show ⇧⌘▲/▼, but it only works when we clicked and focused on the sidebar. ⌥⌘▲/▼ works somehow but it suppose to activate *Bookmarks -> Select Previous/Next Item in Reading List*.

Comment: Hack: cmd-shift-down/up seem to work, if you first shift focus with cmd-L or similar.